# Why the SLURM doesn't provide the nodes as is requested?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

My situation is the cluster consisted of 3 PCs (Raspbian with slurm 18), all connected together with shared file storage, mounted as `/storage`.

The task file is `/storage/multiple_hello.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --nodes=3 
#SBATCH --ntasks=3
cd  /storage
srun echo "Hello World from $(hostname)" >> ./"$SLURM_JOB_ID"_$(hostname).txt
```

It is ran as `sbatch /storage/multiple_hello.sh` and the expected outcome is creating in `/storage` 3 files named `120_node1.txt`, `121_node2.txt` and `122_node3.txt` (arbitrary job numbers) since:

- 3 nodes were requested
- 3 tasks were requested
- there was set a limitation for 1 node per task

Real output: created one file only: `120_node1.txt`

How to make it work as intended?

Weird enoughh, the `srun --nodes=3 hostname` works as expected, and returns:

```
node1
node2
node3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result, modify the last line as

```
srun bash -c 'echo "Hello World from $(hostname)" >> ./"$SLURM_JOB_ID"_$(hostname).txt'
```

The way Bash parses the line is different from what you are expecting. First, `$hostname` and `$SLURM_JOBID` are expanded on the first node of the allocation (the one that runs the submission script), then `srun` is run, and its output is appended to the file. You need to be specific that the redirection `>>` is part of what you want `srun` to do. With the above solution, the variable and command expansions are done on each node, as well as the redirection.